# fb:comments-count tag not working in razor view

Tags: facebook, razor, facebook-comments

I put facebook comment tag in razor view page.

`<fb:comments-count href=http://example.com/></fb:comments-count> awesome comments`

it breaks my page. is there a way to fix it?

Comment: define: "breaks my page"

Answer (score 1):

You may not have included the facebook xml namespace in your `<html>` tag.

`<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`